# Yii How to change Yum flash message for success, error, default

Tags: php, flash, yii

I am working on Yii. I got stuck at one point where I was using `Yum::setFlash` message but I was unble to show flash message for success, error and default.

```
Yum::setFlash(Yum::t("User updated successfully, Activation link sent to ".$new_email."."));
```

this message is always coming with background color gray I want to change that background color with green for success and red for error

[image: Flash message view]

Comment: show your flash message view?

Comment: I have uploaded view picture but some error is coming while loading the same picture

Comment: you can add css for that.